# Show named query proposals/warnings in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

i'm working with eclipse kepler with JBoss tools.
Let's say I have a class named "People", in this class I have an `org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery` or a `javax.persistence.NamedQuery`, with the name "People.findActives".
When i work, to call this named queries I write this:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("People.findActives").list();
```

when using javax.persistence.EntityManager, or

```
session.getNamedQuery("People.findActives").list();
```

when using org.hibernate.Session.

But let's say some developer from my team just changes the name of the query in the class People. He can do it, and the code won't accuse any errors or warnings, so the code is gonna be inconsistent.
And another thing is, when hitting Ctrl+Space, it would be very cool if eclipse searches all the named queries and show the suggestions.

Anyone has the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define string constants for query names and use the constants everywhere instead of the name string, e.g.:

```
@NamedQuery(name=Poeple.FIND_ACTIVITIES, ...)
public class Poeple {
    public static final String FIND_ACTIVITIES = "findActivities";
    ...
}
```

I've made the constant name uppercase to respect common java conventions, but you could use `findActivities` if you really want to.

Comment: Cool, i didn't knew that it was possible to referece static final variables on annotations. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My post, [Avoid hard-coding Hibernate properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958056/avoid-hard-coding-hibernate-properties), explains my approach to dealing with the **exact** problem you are trying to avoid.

My solution has some limitations, but it does work.  Hope it helps.