# Avoid hard-coding Hibernate properties

Tags: java, hibernate

I do not include use hard-coded Hibernate property names in my source code to avoid potential bugs if the database, or the Hibernate configuration, is changed.

I always use Hibernate Criteria and the following HibernateUtils.getPropertyName() method I created to accomplish this.

```
/**
* Get a Hibernate property name.<p>
*
* <b>NOTE:</b> This method assumes all property names start with a lower-case character.
*
* @param methodChecker
 *        - An ignored value. This parameter is a place-holder for a call to the "get" method for the property of interest.
 * @param methodName
 *        - The name of the "get" method used to retrieve the property of interest
 * @return The property name
 */
public static String getPropertyName(Object methodChecker, String methodName)
{
    String propertyName;
    if (methodName.startsWith("get"))
    {
        propertyName = methodName.substring(3, 4).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
                + methodName.substring(4);
    }
    else if (methodName.startsWith("is"))
    {
        propertyName = methodName.substring(2, 3).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)
                + methodName.substring(3);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("method name did not start with 'is' or 'get'");
    }

    return propertyName;
}
```

To use it, I call the "get" method for the property as the first parameter and I hard-code the name of that “get” method for the second property.

Using this approach, Hibernate configuration or database changes will result in **COMPILE-TIME ERRORS** instead of **RUN-TIME ERRORS**.

For example, the following code would result in a **RUN-TIME ERROR** if the *vendor* property was renamed *vendorname*.

*Product product = (Product) session.createCriteria(Product.class).add(Property.forName("vendor").eq(vendor)).uniqueResult();*

To fix the code, all occurrences of *vendor* would have to be replaced with *vendorname*.  Obviously, this is prone to error and could be very time-consuming.

I achieve the same functionality using the following statement:

*Product product = (Product) session.createCriteria(Product.class).add(Property.forName(HibernateUtils.getPropertyName(myProduct.getVendor(), "getVendor")).eq(vendor)).uniqueResult();*

The second approach will result in **COMPILE-TIME ERRORS** if the *vendor* property is renamed *vendorname* because the getVendor() method will change to getVendorname().

I am wondering if there might be another approach – something that would enable me to eliminate the HibernateUtils.getPropertyName() altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: Most people would do an IDE re-factor on the bean name that will happily fix the method call without changing the string and you will never see a compile time error anyway.....  This seems like a job for jUnit, not convoluting code to try to prevent future typos.

Comment: dkatzel mentions the same issue below.  It is a good point.  I have been able to avoid it by making a point of using the Hibernate classes as they are generated and never refactoring using the IDE.  Definitely something worth noting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good design. You say you aren't hardcoding the property names but you are.

First, instead of only hardcoding the property name once in you entity, you instead now have hard code it multiple times increasing the chance of typo or yet another place to fix if the design changes.

I wouldn't worry about future proofing your configuration in case a table or column change.  You should have unit and integration tests (you do have tests right?) to actually test that data is correctly read and loaded into your schema (in a test database).  Any change is a database schema is a huge change that will definitely warrant a new update to your code so it is unlikely that it will happen by accident or without notice.  Finally if you just use the hibernate property mapping appropriately, you only have to update a single location when/if a column name changes.

Finally, if you want to change a method name in your objects, all good IDEs will have refactoring support to automatically update all the places that method is used.  That will be harder to do if you are just passing around String names and using Java Bean like names to figure out what method that is.

Comment: Technically, I am not hard-coding property names.  I am purposely hard-coding the name of the get methods for the properties.  This is my simple approach to having the compiler tell me where and when something is broken automatically.  Your typo point is a good one.  To avoid it, **always** cut-and-paste the second param.  Can you please elaborate on your statement "if you just use the hibernate property mapping appropriately"?  This may be what I am missing.  Finally, regarding your last paragraph, all of my Hibernate classes are auto-generated and I never change their contents.